# How to display wordpress posts in three columns?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Seems like a silly question, but I can't display posts in three columns.

I was using this code with bootstrap, but I can't anymore because it somehow breaks other parts of my page. I had to change it.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:-30px">
    <?php 
        $count=0; 
        query_posts('posts_per_page=9'); 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 blog-post thumb">
        <?php get_template_part('content-noticias', get_post_format()); ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
        $count++; 
        if($count == 3 || $count == 6 ) echo '</div><div class="row">';
        endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
```

It would do the work, but not anymore because of that. How to display my posts in columns without bootstrap? Just for information, my content-noticias is:

```
<div class="noticias">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?the_post_thumbnail();?> </a>

    <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

    <div><p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?></p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the `$count` stuff at all. There's no reason to create separate rows every three elements. The bootstrap column structure is setup for column widths and wrapping. Just use CSS to fix any clearing issues. What bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hey man for row you can use css property `flex-flow: row wrap;`  and for child items `flex-basis: 33%;` and any of your items in your post loop will be in 3 columns , and you can change flex basis for other mediaquery for change sie on mobile for example, check this out !

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1335px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 250px;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

@media(max-width: 1333px) {
  .grid-item {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1073px) {
   .grid-item {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 815px) {
  .grid-item {
    flex-basis: 33%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 555px) {
  .grid-item {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='grid-row'>
        <div class='grid-item'>
            <div class="noticias">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </a>

                <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid-item'>
            <div class="noticias">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </a>

                <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid-item'>
            <div class="noticias">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </a>

                <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid-item'>
            <div class="noticias">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </a>

                <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid-item'>
            <div class="noticias">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </a>

                <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid-item'>
            <div class="noticias">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </a>

                <h1 style="margin-top:-30px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 50 ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `$count if` statement:

```
if($count == 3 || $count == 6 ) echo '</div><div class="row">'; <-- THIS WILL NEVER CLOSE
```

What you can do is this:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:-30px">
    <?php 
        query_posts('posts_per_page=9'); 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 blog-post thumb">
        <?php get_template_part('content-noticias', get_post_format()); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Then you can use CSS to make sure your columns stay intact:

```
.row .blog-post:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

That will make sure that every third element will clear so if one of the columns is longer or shorter, it won't mess with the layout.